# ArgoCD: Update applications only after 8 pm?

Tags: argocd

Is it possible using ArgoCD that applications are only rolled out at certain times?

For example, the rollout of a new version whose change is already in the git repository, which is monitored by the gitops tool, should only be rolled out after 8 p.m. or not on the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **sync windows** to enable or disable sync during certain timeslots.

See https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync_windows/